# why request.getParameter is null for a div tag

Tags: servlets

Inside my jsp page 
i have a div as shown below and i am setting the value of it through a javascript event .

```
<div id="panel">Price
            <div id="field_name" name="priceval"></div>
        </div>
```

The issue i am facing here is that , i am getting the priceval value as null

```
String price = request.getParameter("priceval");
int priceval = Integer.parseInt(price);
```

For reference this is my whole jsp file

```
<html>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">

#field_name { display:inline-block; }

</style>

<head>
<title>Online Book Store</title>
<script>



function myFunction() {

    var quantityvalue=document.getElementById("quan").value;
     var selObj = document.getElementById('selSeaShells');
     var optionselectedvalue ;
    // var optionselectedtext;

     for (i=0; i<selObj.options.length; i++) {
           if (selObj.options[i].selected) {
             optionselectedvalue = selObj.options[i].value.split(':')[0];

                }
              }

    var finalprice = quantityvalue*optionselectedvalue;


    mydiv = document.getElementById("panel");
    mydiv.style.display = "block"; //to show it
    document.getElementById("field_name").innerHTML = finalprice;

}

function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    return !(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));
}

function hideDiv() {
    mydiv = document.getElementById("panel");
    mydiv.style.display = "none"; //to hide it  
}
window.onload = function () {
    hideDiv();
}

</script>
</head>
<Body Bgcolor = "wheat" onload="hideDiv()">
<center>
<h2> welcome to online shopping</h2>
<form Action = "./onlinebookstore">
select Book
 <select name = "book" id="selSeaShells">
 <option></option>
 <option value=  "100:C programming language">C programming language</option>
 <option value = "200:Java programming language">Java programming language</option>
 <option value = "300:Network analysis">Network analysis</option>
 <option value = "400:Advaced computer Networks">Advaced computer Networks</option> 
 <option value ="500:Programming analysis">Programming analysis</option>
  <option value = "600:Advanced data strctures">Advanced data strctures</option>
 <option value = "700:Advanced java and web technologies">Advanced java and web technologies</option>
 <option value = "800:Electronic devices">Electronic devices</option>
 <option value = "900:Computer Graphics">Computer Graphics</option>
 <option value = "1000:Microprocessors">Microprocessors</option>
 <option value = "1100:Oracle">Oracle</option>

  </select>
 <br><br>
  quantity <Input type = "text" name = "Quantity" id="quan" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" onblur="myFunction()">
 <br><br>

 <div id="panel">Price
            <div id="field_name" name="priceval"></div>
        </div>

 <input type = "submit" name = "s" value = "ADDItem">
 <input type = "submit" name = "s" value = "Removeitem">
 <input type = "submit" name = "s" value = "showitems">
 <input type = "submit" value = "Logout" name = "s">
 </form>
</center>
</Body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`div` tags are not part of the form submission. You could dynamically create `<input>` tags which could be used in submission. See the [w3](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) reference for div tags.

Answer (score 0):

a `div` is not a parameter, parameters are on the URL or from a `form`.

Answer (score 0):

same as the other answers,, div is not a parameter to be passed... to pass the value of the calculated price you can use hidden input and set it using the javascript with the div and get its value in the servlet.

like that

JSP

```
   <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price">
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("price").value=calculatedPrice;
```

Servlet

```
   price = request.getParameter("price");
```